# 2 Orders From Same Account Information But Different People

Tags: magento-1.8, orders

I have a weird situation I'm wondering how to fix or prevent. I had 2 orders come in with the same account information, but the actually customers were 2 different people. One was the right person with the account information and the other one was a completely different person. They were back to back orders, but come in about hour difference in time. Luckily the payment methods were different, but is there a reason why these 2 orders had the same account information attached to them?